# Сумма определенных значений столбца

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица, в которую записывается показание счетчика. Счетчик может быть сброшен (например, 09.10.23 в 19:03)

| id | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09.10.23 08:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 09.10.23 08:10 | 7 |
| 3 | 09.10.23 08:20 | 10 |
| 4 | 09.10.23 08:30 | 13 |
| 5 | 09.10.23 08:41 | 17 |
| 6 | 09.10.23 08:56 | 26 |
| 7 | 09.10.23 19:03 | 0 |
| 8 | 09.10.23 20:04 | 3 |
| 9 | 09.10.23 21:10 | 7 |
| 10 | 09.10.23 21:15 | 12 |

Нужно в результате получить сумму значений счетчика за день (26 + 12 = 38). Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким SQL запросом это можно сделать?

Comment: можно решать через оконные функции, а можно найти все нули (или конец дня) и вытащить последнее значение до этого id/времени

Comment: Я сам не осилю, подскажите, пожалуйста, как должны выглядеть данные запросы

Comment: вы для начала укажите версию SQL Server, которая у вас в наличии и сдалайте фиддл с тестовыми данными на несколько дней. Тут в частности не помешает знать, вам выборку надо делать за один день, или за интервал дней с разбиением по этим дням.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (14.0.3445.2). Нужна выборка за один день.

Comment: А сброс счётчика (0) записывется всегда или как попадёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LEAD([count]) OVER (ORDER BY [date]) lead_count
  FROM test
)
SELECT SUM(count)
FROM cte
WHERE lead_count < [count] OR lead_count IS NULL
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OCWWQcM8)

Comment: Спасибо! Данный запрос оказался проще, понятнее и без ошибок

Answer (score 0):

Самый сложный метод, это соединяться с этим же экземпляром таблицы, по `id` и `id+1`, таким образом мы можем отловить событие "сброса" сравнивая `count` с соседом. Скажем, ваша таблица это `templ`:

```
-- Создаем таблицу
CREATE TABLE templ (
    id NUMBER,
    date_time TIMESTAMP,
    count NUMBER
);
```

```
select t1.count from templ t1
join templ t2 on
t1.id+1 = t2.id
where t1.count>t2.count
```

А потом соединяем это с самым последним значением по `id`:

```
select t1.count from templ t1
  where t1.id = (select max(id) from templ t1)
```

И находим `sum` между всеми `count`:

```
select sum(count) from (select t1.count from templ t1
join templ t2 on
t1.id+1 = t2.id
where t1.count>t2.count
union all
select t1.count from templ t1
  where t1.id = (select max(id) from templ t1))
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UPda5Hu9) *(делал на oracle, но для sql server вполне рабочий вариант)*

Comment: это не будет работать, если id с пропусками/не последовательны

Comment: @teran по данному примеру всё последовательно, значит не вижу проблем

Comment: Спасибо за метод, смысл понял, но реализовать так и не получилось из-за ошибок